# iOS iPhone - NSArray get object next & previous

Tags: core-data, nsarray

```
(
"<Songs: 0xa4f3510> (entity: Songs; id: 0xa4f2db0 <x-coredata://C569FCE5-9DE8-4421-AE91-7649ABB0276C/Songs/p1> ; data: {\n    name = \"Lil Wayne ft  Birdman Future Mack Maine Nicki Minaj - Tapout (CDQ NoShout) (2012)  www RnB4U in \";\n})",
"<Songs: 0xa4f0f70> (entity: Songs; id: 0xa4f2dc0 <x-coredata://C569FCE5-9DE8-4421-AE91-7649ABB0276C/Songs/p2> ; data: {\n    name = \"Matador (IE) - Svinx\";\n})",
"<Songs: 0x1c7e2470> (entity: Songs; id: 0xa499680 <x-coredata://C569FCE5-9DE8-4421-AE91-7649ABB0276C/Songs/p3> ; data: {\n    name = \"Cherno Feredje - Kaka Dora (heminei com)\";\n})"
)
```

how to get only `name = .......... from array`

and how to search in NSArray and If I found name to have button next and when I click next I want to get next name in the array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an array of all the names and all the songs, you can use `NSArray *names = [resultsArray valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.name"]`

Answer (score 0):

To search an `NSArray` you need to use a `NSPredicate` and the `-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` method on `NSArray`.

In this case if you are searching for name you can code something like:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", someNameValue];
NSArray *filtered = [myResultsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```